# Educational course nomenclature

Tags: word-choice, nouns

I am looking for a noun to describe an individual meeting of a **course**, as in a course of study at a university. **Class** is not an option in this case. Thoughts?

Comment: Let me guess: you're looking for an identifier for individual classes, but your programming language and naming convention preclude you from using `class`.

Comment: @Jon Purdy Yes, however I also have to account for different logical components, all of which could be referred to as 'class'. I've settled on 'course', 'schedule' and 'meeting'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are several options, depending on the nature of the course. I have provided examples in each case:

- *[Class](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/class) [meeting/period]*

  > Are we going to have music theory class tomorrow?
- *[Course](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/course) meeting*

  > Your professor will determine course meeting times.
- *[Lab](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laboratory) [session]*

  > - We have lab twice a week.
  > - How many lab sessions must we attend for Organic Chemistry?
- [*Lecture*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lecture)

  > Yesterday's real analysis lecture was so boring!
- [*Recitation*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recitation)

  > You must attend daily recitations for psychology.
- [*Seminar*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seminar?show=0&t=1294706928)

  > The bioinformatics course offers two mandatory seminars each week.
- *[Tutorial](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/tutorial) session/meeting*

  > - What time is the physics tutorial [session]?
  > - My music analysis tutorial meeting was so much fun!

Comment: @Adam Lassek: No problem! Sorry, I couldn't resist including *class*, as I wasn't too sure what your reason for its exclusion was :)