# What word describes a university class in both the UK and the US?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, american-english, synonyms, british-english

In the US words like *class*, *subject*, *course* are used to describe a university class, while in the UK, words like *subject* and *course* are used to describe the name of the whole university degree. Instead in the UK words like *module* or *unit* are used to describe a university class.

Is there a word that will be understood by both British English speakers and American English speakers?

UPDATE: by university class I meant a series of lectures on a topic e.g. "Economics 101" or "Introduction to Statistics".

Comment: great question!

Comment: As a Brit, I found it hard to understand your question, because I didn't know what a _class_ meant. We don't usually use that word at all in connection with college or university, but only school (which means high school or elementary school), and it refers to a single session with a teacher. From your question, I deduce that to you it means a series of sessions on a subject - what I would call a _course_. In answer to your question, I doubt it.

Comment: Colin Fine, it's worth making another point for the benefit of non-British people reading your comment. In the UK, the terms *high school* and *elementary school* are not normally, used. They are called *secondary school* and *primary school*.

Comment: Slightly related: *[Educational course nomenclature](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8438)*, *[English translation for the different parts of a course as found in French schools/universities](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79743)*, *[Term for a person who conducts practice lessons](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154510)*.

Comment: Also, in the UK there is a national curriculum and a national top-down education system. Neither is true in the U.S, especially at the college level. Plus, "class" can mean a number of different things, sometimes simultaneously.

Comment: Would "lesson" work?

Comment: Still on the subject of the impenetrability of some commonplace educational terminology, in the U.S. the non-self-explanatory notion of the [*credit hour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_hour) is prevalent.

Comment: @Colin: If by *course*, you mean a series of lectures on a given topic, the word works for the U.S. as well.

Comment: Here to confirm that *course* also works in Canadian English.  It seems to be rather universal term, perhaps the best one to answer this question.

Comment: See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/104197/the-meaning-of-paper-in-the-context-of-undergraduate-students

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research I came to a conclusion that it's hard to use a single word to explain the concept to both UK people and US people.

I found that among UK universities the word `module` is widely used to describe a series of university lectures on a topic e.g. "Economics 101" or "Introduction to Statistics". Although there are a few universities that interchangeably use both `module` and `unit`.

In the US however, I found that word `course` is used by universities to describe a series of university lectures on a topic. In contrast, UK universities use word `course` as well as word `subject` to describe degree names e.g.: `A 3-year course in Anthropology` or `A table of subjects provided at university`.

As such, I'd recommend using word `module` in the UK and word `course` in the US to describe a series of university lectures on a topic.

Comment: *Module* works just fine among Americans too, although there may be some expectation that a course contains more than just one module.  (Really, there will be no problem when module=course, but the connotation may be that "this module was so important it was given its own entire course")

Answer (score 2):

*Unit* works for both US and UK.  I work for an international company and do the LMS.  The words course and unit are almost interchangeable.  The only issue for US universities is sometimes they calculate hours in units, but that should almost help your language barrier.

Answer (score 0):

*Period,* perhaps?  If you mean each day's lesson rather than the subject as a whole.

Since Australian English is a mash-up of American and British English, I thought I'd add a bit to the comments above.

In high school (approx ages 12-18), the *subject* would be Maths or English and a *class* or *period* would be the 75-minute lesson for that day.

- In university, say you were undertaking a Bachelor of Arts in Communication (Writing and Cultural Studies), that would be your *degree*.
- Your *courses* are the one of three or four *subjects* you take each semester, e.g. Genre Studies.
- Your *classes* are the day-to-day lessons you attend for your subject/course, these can be either lectures or tutorials, but mostly in reference to tutorials as these take place generally in a classroom.
- In my experience, *modules* are topics within your subject/course, e.g. a different genre of writing each module.
- Then moving on to *units*, in Australia, these correspond to each subject and signify their weight to the overall number of units that need to be completed to finish your degree.

I know you weren't asking about Australia but I've often found that Australian systems are very similar to UK and US ones. Hope it helped a bit!